# Scala case option with empty list

Tags: scala

Let's set:

```
val l = List(("AA",473.3), ("BB",676.48), ("AA",685.45), ("GG",812.73))
```

I want to get the sum of all values that have "AA" in the tuple. It works quite well with this:

```
var totAA = l.collect{ case ("AA",v) => v }.sum
```

But if `l` is an empty list, I get this error:

```
cmd78.sc:1: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: Nothing
var totAA = l.collect{ case ("AA",v) => v }.sum
                            ^cmd78.sc:1: ambiguous implicit values:
 both object BigIntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type scala.math.Numeric.BigIntIsIntegral.type
 and object IntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type scala.math.Numeric.IntIsIntegral.type
 match expected type Numeric[B]
var totAA = l.collect{ case ("AA",v) => v }.sum
```

So I tried this:

```
var totAA = l.collect{ case List() => 0.0; case ("AA",v) => v }.sum
```

But I get the same error, a bit less verbose:

```
cmd78.sc:1: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: Nothing
var totAA = l.collect{ case List() => 0.0; case ("AA",v) => v }.sum
                                                ^
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code works perfectly fine for both empty and non-empty lists.

Here the non-empty one:

```
val l = List(("AA",473.3), ("BB",676.48), ("AA",685.45), ("GG",812.73))
var totAA = l.collect{ case ("AA",v) => v }.sum
println(totAA) // output: 1158.75
```

Same for empty one:

```
val l = List.empty[(String, Double)]
var totAA = l.collect{ case ("AA",v) => v }.sum
println(totAA) // output: 0.0
```

Are you sure that you created an empty `List[(String, Double)]`, and not an empty `List[Nothing]`? `Nothing` cannot be pattern-matched against `("AA", v)`, because it's obviously not a tuple. `Nothing` by definition cannot be pattern-matched against anything at all, because there are no values of type `Nothing`.

Comment: Probably OP initialised his empty list like `val l = List()` or ~None~ `Nil`, whithout type annotation or type arguments, in which case the inferred type is `List[Nothing]`.

Comment: @oowekyala `Nil`, not `None`. That was kind-of implied by the rhetorical question in the end of my answer.

Comment: thank you, I just couldn't force it to be List[(String, Double)] as it was a result of a map. maybe I could have overmaped it but it manage it in an other way